# Rubymine PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, sockets, jdbc, vagrant, rubymine

I'm trying to connect to my postgres DB inside a vagrant setup using Rubymine and I'm having trouble. Any help would greatly be appreciated. JDBC is a new front for me.

192.168.50.50 is what I've used in my vagrant file as

```
 config.vm.network :private_network, ip: '192.168.50.50'
```

This is how my DB settings in Rubymine look like.

[image]

I keep getting the following error

```
java.sql.SQLException: The connection attempt failed.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:225)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:64)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:136)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:29)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:21)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:31)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:24)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:410)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:280)
    in RemoteDriverImpl.connect(RemoteDriverImpl.java:27)
    in RemoteUtil.access$100(RemoteUtil.java:36)
    in RemoteUtil$RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteUtil.java:227)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy97.connect(Unknown Source)
    in LocalDataSource.getConnection(LocalDataSource.java:240)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.readMore(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:143)
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.ensureBytes(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:112)
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.read(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:71)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.ReceiveChar(PGStream.java:269)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:376)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:173)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:64)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:136)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:29)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:21)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:31)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:24)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:410)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:280)
    in RemoteDriverImpl.connect(RemoteDriverImpl.java:27)
```

Port 3000 is the forwarded port and I am also using SSH tunnel.

If I attempt to connect without the host and port values (i.e. leaving only the SSH info) I end up with this

```
java.sql.SQLException: The connection attempt failed.
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:225)
at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:64)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:136)
at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:29)
at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:21)
at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:31)
at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:24)
at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:410)
at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:280)
in RemoteDriverImpl.connect(RemoteDriverImpl.java:27)
in RemoteUtil.access$100(RemoteUtil.java:36)
in RemoteUtil$RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteUtil.java:227)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy97.connect(Unknown Source)
in LocalDataSource.getConnection(LocalDataSource.java:240)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.ReceiveChar(PGStream.java:271)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.enableSSL(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:286)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:105)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:64)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:136)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:29)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:21)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:31)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:24)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:410)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:280)
    in RemoteDriverImpl.connect(RemoteDriverImpl.java:27)
```

It would mean a lot if someone could help

Comment: @WilliamJanoti please do see the edit above :)

Comment: I'm getting a similar error in RubyMine. Rails console has no problem seeing the local postgres database, but Rubymine fails every time:

Connection to Rails branch: development failed java.sql.SQLException: The connection attempt failed. at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:225) at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:64) at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:136) at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection....

Comment: @AlexEdelstein check the ports and if you're on vagrant configure the SSH settings in Rubymine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those who might be in the same position, check your ports in postgres. Open 5432 and configure that in ruby mine and you should be ready to go.